# is it safe to use .net static Path class when using TPL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

Is it safe to use `Path.GetFileName()` or `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` inside a method that is ran in Parallel?

ex:

I have the following

```
var test = files.AsParallel().Select(x => this.MatchFileDirectory(x, dirs));
```

and inside `MatchFileDirectory` I would be calling `Path.GetFileName()`. Is there any drawback on performance?

Comment: did you read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Microsoft have a [standard blurb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx#threadSafetyToggle) that `public static` members are thread safe, including for `Path`.

Comment: And the next "I never read the documentation" question. It is clear, right there. Thread Safety is determined for every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no drawback to use that inside a `Task`. Unless you might expect, it doesn't even do any disk IO operations, it is just an all .NET method without any external needs. So nothing to worry about.

Check out the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,856):

```
public static String GetFileName(String path) {
  if (path != null) {
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path);

        int length = path.Length;
        for (int i = length; --i >= 0;) {
            char ch = path[i];
            if (ch == DirectorySeparatorChar || ch == AltDirectorySeparatorChar || ch == VolumeSeparatorChar)
                return path.Substring(i + 1, length - i - 1);

        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are perfectly safe - the string contents that you are passing to the method is immutable so cannot be changed, and the `Path.GetFileName()` method call is deterministic and has no side-effects:

> Most members of the Path class do not interact with the file system and do not verify the existence of the file specified by a path string. Path class members that modify a path string, such as ChangeExtension, have no effect on names of files in the file system.